# Returned array of objects values comma-seperated in html input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to display comma separated values in input field html. 
Result: `First Value, Second Value, Third Value`. 
Values are returned in isolated scope of directive (custom-directive-button) as `selectedItems`.

Input part in html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selected" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" selected-items = "appModel.selectedItems" custom-directive-button>!</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in appModel.selectedItems">{{ item.attrValue }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Returned object "selectedItems" looks like this:

```
[{"attrValue": "First Value","descText": "First Value in array"},{"attrValue": "Second Value","descText": "Second Value in array"},{"attrValue": "Third Value","descText": "Third Value in array"}]
```

Is it possible to achieve it somehow with Angular JS (filter) or with JQuery.

Other requirement is to have this functionality both way.
So if user will type something into the input field, it will automatically update as well `selectedItems` with typed `attrValue, and <NA> as description`.

Thanks.

Comment: I was thinking to do in controller convertor, and then via isolated scope pass already comma-separated value `comma-separated-value=appModel.commaSeparatedValue`, which I can then bind to input field with `ng-model=commaSeparatedValue`. But this solution seems to me not a good idea, because I need to enable user to type new value in input field - that it works as well other way. And in this case i will need to create other convertor, which will take comma separated value and create array of object from it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to add an answer:

I have created separate directive attrFormatter, where methods ngModel.formatters is taking care to parse and format values to comma separated result and ngModel.parsers is doing same thing but vice versa.

```
angular.module('modul').directive('attrFormatter', attrFormatter);

  function attrFormatter() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (inputValues) {
                var formattedValues = [];

                if (angular.isArray(inputValues)) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) {
                        formattedValues.push(inputValues[i].neededValue);
                    }
                    return formattedValues.join(',').toUpperCase();
                }
                return inputValues;
            });


            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                return (value || '').split(',').map(function (selValues) {
                    return selValues.trim();
                });
            });
        }
    }
};
```

}

Then you just need to add your directive tag into your html:

{ 
`<attr-formatter ng-model="neededItems"/>`
}

NeededItems is an array of returned values to be parsed.