# get values from an array into comma separated list with dynamic name before every values

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Html:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="data.price1[$index]" ng-change="pricecalc1($index)" placeholder="Enter Product Price">
```

js:

ng-model declaration :

```
$scope.data={price1:[]};
```

I'm inserting dynamic values into this array and it results as {["100,200,300"]}

But i need to insert the dynamic values like this {["100","200","300"]} or [{price: '100'},{price:'200'},{price:'300'}];

Help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the code that should insert values to the array. Am I blind or why I don't see one? Html has a call to function, but what the function does actually?

Comment: Am just asking what should i change in the ng-model $scope.data={price1:[]}; so that i can  get the result like this {["val","val","val"]}

Comment: whatever you are entering in the input field the ng-model($scope.data.price1) results as {["val1,val2,val3,...etc"]}

Comment: Do you enter to field "val1, val2" or those one by one? At least in the first case the result is like that you said.

Comment: Does your question have answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295431/returned-array-of-objects-values-comma-seperated-in-html-input-field

Comment: So basically you need a directive to handle parse and formatting of the field values.